# Path, FileInfo, etc. in PCL (Profile 158)

Tags: c#, portable-class-library

I can concatenate files and paths, but how do I check for file existing using PCL (Profile 158). Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Platforms such as Windows Store and Silverlight don't support those APIs.  Those platforms have APIs such as Windows.Storage and IsolatedStorage which allow access to storage.  You can use my [PCL Storage library](http://pclstorage.codeplex.com/) or something similar to access those different APIs in a portable fashion.