# FileInfo equivalent in code analysis in C#

Tags: c#, code-analysis, portable-class-library

I'm currently in the process of writing analysis code for my job. I have to  "map" the code from FxCop to our own private framework. This is a bit of an issue, but not my main concern. I can't access the FileInfo class, my ultimate preview 2015 VS asked me if I wanted to generated it. So, basically, I'm asking what's the equivalent of the FileInfo class while doing code analysis? I've looked into the FileVersionInfo class, but I'm not quite sure if that's the way to go ?

**EDITS**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
namespace SomeNamespace
{
    public class SomeFileValidationClass
    {
        public FileInfo FileInfo { get; private set; }

        public SomeFileValidationClass(FileInfo fileInfo)
        {
            this.FileInfo = fileInfo;
            _failedResults = new List<SomeRuleResult>();
        }

//Code missing, but the point still remains that FileInfo can't be accessed.
}
```

Comment: *Why* can't you access the `FileInfo` class?

Comment: We have to ask this: Have you referenced the namespace `System.IO`?

Comment: Yes I did haha, I would have felt a bit out of place if I did not and posted a question. I'll update my post with some of my code.

Comment: Why I can't access the FileInfo class goes beyond me, I don't know at the moment

Comment: You should be able to right click and view definition! :D But if all else fails, manual : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Do you have any namespace called 'FileInfo' ? It could be that you forgot to put 'using' before the namespace, might give this error as well.

Comment: Agree with @Caramiriel, there has to be something else in the solution blocking it, that compiles fine for me

Comment: When I've looked at my error, I have this : "CS0246 : The type or namespace "FileInfo" could not be found. (Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I'm going to ask around to some co-workers to see if my issue was also found on their computers or if I'm the only having this issue

Comment: I've tagged this with [tag:portable-class-library] per your comment on Justin's answer - it would be helpful to identify what targets it has, as not all support `FileInfo`

Comment: I'm so sorry :/ I actually had no idea I was in a portable library project... I'll pay more attention next time.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20558044/50447

Comment: Good thanks, I'll look more into this !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation [`FileInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is located in the `System.IO` namespace of `mscorlib`, so it should be present without needing any other references.

My only suggestion is that you are compiling against some odd version of `mscorlib` that doesn't have it for some reason, maybe its a bug in VS2015, or perhaps you have downloaded and built [corefx](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx)?

Comment: I've looked into it, and my software architect validated it, but I'm still wondering why though.. The reason why FileInfo cannot be access it because I'm in a portable library .